# Is Simondon's ontogenesis compatible with Badiou's ontology?

Tags: ontology, badiou

Is Simondon's ontogenesis compatible with Badiou's ontology?

Simondon's belief is that an individual can only be understood as an individuation, presupposing a pre-individual metastable reality, that results from a strucuration of two disparate fields.

This seems similar to Badiou's set theoretical ontology of the event, but I am not sure enough of the nuances of Badiou's ontology to make this claim definitively.